# How to fetch strings from a text document in java?

Tags: java, database, string, fetch

I am looking to convert a large text document into individual strings based on what line the sentences are found on. Is there a way to access the text document in java and designate each line as a separate string? Or at least quickly convert all of it by importing it to a java file?

Comment: Read the file into an ArrayList. Iterate through the the ArrayList and the index into the ArrayList becomes your line number.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553673/split-very-large-text-file-by-max-rows

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be reading all lines in the file (when the file is small) into an `ArrayList` by using the `readAllLines`() method available in `Files` class. Then you can pull the line you are interested in by using the line number:

```
public static String getLine(String filename, int lineNum) throws IOException {
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename));
  return (lines.size() >= lineNum) ? lines.get(lineNum - 1) : null;
}
```

This method can also take a charset parameter, to read as per a specific character encoding:

```
public static String getLine(String filename, int lineNum) throws IOException {
  Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename), charset);
  return (lines.size() >= lineNum) ? lines.get(lineNum - 1) : null;
}
```

But for larger files, you can use Stream APIs (Java 8):

```
public static String getLine(String filename, int lineNum) throws IOException {
  try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
    Optional<String> line = lines.skip(lineNum - 1).findFirst();
    return line.isPresent() ? line.get() : null;
  }
}
```

Using `BufferedReader`:

```
public static String getLine(String filename, int lineNum) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    for (int i = 0; i < lineNum - 1; ++i) {
        reader.readLine();
    }
  return reader.readLine();
}
```