# How to optimize the memory usage for large file processing

Tags: java, heap-memory

I have a file and from file I am populating the `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Objects>>`. HashMap size will be 25 for sure, means 25 keys, but the List will be huge say million records for each key.

So what I use to do now is for each key retrieve the list of records and process them parallel using threads. Things went on good until I faced the larger file and so I am facing the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

I would like to ask you what is the best way instead populating the HashMap with the list of objects? What I am thinking is to get the 25 offsets of the file and instead of putting the lines I read from file into the arrayList, put the offset of the file and give each thread an iterator to iterate from its start offset to end offset. I still have to try this thought. But before I execute, I would like to know any better ways to optimize memory usage.

Comment: Why don't you assign more memory to the JVM using the -Xmx command line parameter ?

Comment: Some times the file could be of 100GB too and multiple runnings of this application would also happen frequently.. So it might never be enough and could go into the same memory issue.

Comment: Your approach with the offsets seems good. Although you can have concurrency problems on the OS level, I would separate the big file into 25 separate files and process each one in each thread. That way your HashMap would be <String, File>

Comment: Why? Do you really need the entire file in memory? This rare.

Comment: Well, It was the way as you said before in our application. There was 25 splitted files. But there is a huge overhead when to split the file into 25 mini files which has to go through huge splitting and its taking lot of time. And so I am looking forward to execute this way, time efficient.

Comment: No definitely not needed in memory. And so the reason, i thought an idea of giving offsets to threads. Looking for any better idea.

Comment: Well actually this module is all about file manipulations. Use of database could only be in service layer. And so I could not really choose database.

Comment: It depends on how you are reading the file. Don't just open it, use something as RandomAccessFile and read then in smaller blocks.

Comment: If each list is continuous in the file (you say you could just store the offset of the beginning of the list) then why do you first need to find out which keys there are? Can't you just go through the file and read as you go - you encounter a key, you then process the list behind it, forget about the data you've loaded and then continue with the next key?

Comment: In that case, I cant use multi-threading concept. I had to go sequentially. I wanted to process all keys parallel and so the reason I got them mapped into the hashmap getting all records according to the key and then process them parallel.

Comment: When you said a dictionary of file offsets, I read Index. Database is great for doing this. Otherwise, if you really need to load a file that's larger than available memory and you can't process the file as a stream, as you need frequent random access, you might want to look at mmap-ing the file.

Comment: I finally used Producer Consumer approach to achieve the huge file processing. Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

> I will populate the `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Objects>>`

After populating the `HashMap` what do you need to do with it? I believe that just populating the Map is not your task. Whatever the scenario, you don't need to read the whole file in memory.

Increasing the heap size may not be a good solution as someday you may get a file even bigger than your heap size.

Read the file in chunks using a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) or [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) depending on your needs and do your task as you read. The two APIs only read a part of the file in memory at a time.

> I read from file into the arrayList, put the offset of the file and give each thread an iterator to iterate from its start offset to end offset. I still have to try this thought.

Using multiple threads will not prevent `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` because all the threads will be in same JVM. Furthermore, no matter you read the file in one list or multiple lists, all the data from the file will be read into the same heap memory.

If you mention what you actually want to do with the data from file, this answer can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto what ares said. Need more information. What do you plan on doing with the map. Is it an operation that requires the whole file to be loaded onto memory ? Or can it be done in parts ?

Also, have you considered splitting the file into parts once its size surpasses a threshold size ?

Like Pshemo's answer here : [How to break a file into pieces using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864317/how-to-break-a-file-into-pieces-using-java)

Also, If you want to process in parallel, you could consider processing a map which covers a part of the file. Process that map in parallel and store the results in a queue of some sort. Provided the queue will contain a subset of the data you are processing(to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions).

Comment: I think you have not read the comments below my question. I also mentioned that I wont do file splitting because of the huge overhead. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Deepak. Didn't realize back then. Did your offset idea work ?

Comment: I realized even for the offsets, threads should parallely open the same file to read their offsets, which will have IO performance issue. So I implemented the producer-consumer approach to solve this.