# How can I merge 500 files in a single file in android?

Tags: android, arrays, file, merge

I want to merge around 500 files in a single file in android. I can do it in java like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864346) but it gives me of lamda in android studio. Is there any better way to do it in android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is in the answer you linked... Just use the first method he refers to, about joining files, above the lamba one. If you are trying to create a list of files, do that using any other method not using lamba.. either by listng your 500 files. or google , get all files in folder

Comment: @Doomsknight That is for splitting of a file.

Comment: The method called `mergeFiles` ? Its there, check again :) 2nd one in his post.

Comment: @Doomsknight I tried that but it's importing the MediaStore.Files class. It doesn't show any Files class.