# io.socket restarts when sending large files from Android

Tags: android, socket.io, upload, large-files

I am using this library

```
api('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

I am sending files using the code below. It works for small files up to about 6MB. But for larger files, like 30MB, it attempts to upload for about 5 seconds but then the socket automatically "reconnects" without uploading.

```
        input = file.inputStream()
        byteArray = input.readBytes()

        val fileJson = JSONObject()
        fileJson.put("file", byteArray)
        socket.emit("media/upload", fileJson)
```

The server end seems fine, because it works from web to web.

Am I not doing it right?

Comment: What is mb? Milli bit?

Comment: @blackapps Mega Bytes of course

Comment: You dont know the abbreviation/notation for mega bytes? And what would Mb stand for according to your standard?

Comment: You think they are not to the point? And the answer/cause is pretty obvious. As is your mistake.

Comment: indeed. We're talking about file sizes, being sent using programming language. It's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when dealing with files (100Mb), I then split the file into several small chunks/packets (1024 bytes), then make sure you don't create a new connection for every packet, you can then you can always write the packets to disk to get the file.

for splitting file you can reference [How to break a file into pieces using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864317/how-to-break-a-file-into-pieces-using-java)

It also has a sample on merging the file back

This is not the best solution but will get you going.