# Split a zip file into multiple files files using java

Tags: java, split, zip

Hello I need to split a zip file into multiple samaller files,
ex. file.zip is splitted into files with fixed size less than 640MB and format nameOfZip.zip.001

I am currently looking for some kind of a java library that would be able to do this. If there is no such, advice would be very helpful too.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to break a file into pieces using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10864317)

Comment: I will give it a shot, thank you

Comment: if you want post it as answer and I will mark it as accepted

Comment: There is no need to repeat same answer in many places. We have *duplicates* system for that so I marked your question as duplicate of question I lined earlier. Don't think having question marked as duplicate is something bad. Duplicates are meant to be road signs leading to correct answer, so they are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip, the format, can do this. You can then unzip the batch of files with plain jane `unzip` on the command line (or with tools like p7zip and such, or you can just doubleclick the zip on a mac, etcetera).

Unfortunately, the baked in zip support in java can't make split zips. But, [Lingala / Zip4j](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j) *can* do it.

Add that library to your list of dependencies and use its API (forget about `java.io.ZipOutputStream`, or the Zip FileSystem - anything that starts with `java.*` can't do this.

Alternatively it is trivial to write code in java to just split any file. You'd need to write java code as well to put them back together, or you need to know a few things about your OS to do this (e.g. `cat a.bin b.bin >c.bin` on posix OSes will put a.bin and b.bin back together). This isn't difficult at all, just your basic file and outputstream support can trivially put it together in less than a page's worth of java code. No libraries exist, and probably never will - that is a very simple task that isn't common enough to make a library for.

So, if that's what you're looking for, go ahead and write it yourself. All you need is the javadoc of `java.nio.file.Paths` and `java.nio.file.Files`.

Comment: I really hoped there would be an out-of-the box solution, but I guess I will write it on my own. Thanks